# Django: Как передать в Celery task уникальный идентификатор pk

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery

Есть форма для загрузки файла, необходимо сделать так, чтобы после загрузки файла его статус был Pendig, а спустя 5 секунд менялся на Success. Подскажите как это реализовать.

models.py

```py
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default='False')
```

views.py

```py
def home(request):
    files = UploadFile.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_file_form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if upload_file_form.is_valid():
            upload_file_form.save()
            return redirect(home)
    else:
        upload_file_form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'testfileapp/home.html', {
        'files': files,
        'upload_file_form': upload_file_form,
    })
```

signals.py

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import UploadFile
from .tasks import set_status_as_inactive


@receiver(post_save, sender=UploadFile)
def notify(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        set_status_as_inactive.delay(instance.pk)
```

tasks.py

```py
from celery import shared_task
from testfileapp.models import UploadFile
import time


@shared_task
def set_status_as_inactive(pk):
    file = UploadFile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    time.sleep(5)
    file.is_active = True
```

И как это все связать, чтобы отображалось в шаблоне

UPD Разобрался с импортом и набросал таск, но на странице статус с False на True не меняется, в чем проблема? Таск явно не лучший и возможно не рабочий, помогите)

Answer (score 0):

> UPD Разобрался с импортом и набросал таск, но на странице статус с False на True не меняется, в чем проблема? Таск явно не лучший и возможно не рабочий, помогите)

`file.save()` стоит попробовать

Итоговый вариант:

```
@shared_task
def set_status_as_inactive(pk):
    file = UploadFile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    time.sleep(5)
    file.is_active = True
    file.save()
```